# Реализация метода Хопфилда

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, нейронные-сети

Добрый день! Много прочитал в интернете статей на эту тему и не до конца понял как этот метод реализуется. Может есть блок схема или псевдокод этого алгоритма?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/301406/ читали уже?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy да, читал, но там плохо описано и еще хуже реализовано. Точнее не хуже реализовано, а запутаннее. Наглядное доказательство этому структура neuro_net_system